# zsh: read:-p: no coprocess error while using read command with -p flag

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, zsh

community. I recently started to use zsh instead of bash and now i'm getting some problems that cannot be found on bash.
One of theme: when i use `read -p` command, obviously with flag -p, i get an error that says:

read: -p: no coprocess

On the other hand when I switch to bash again, this command works perfectly.

My full command:

```
read -p "what's your name" name
```

Thank you for help <3

Answer (score 12):

The usage is not compatible between shells.

As explained in `man zshbuiltins`, the way to emit a prompt string for a `zsh` `read` command is to append it to the identifier name after a `?`:

> ```
>           If the first argument contains a `?', the remainder of this word
>           is used as a prompt on standard error when the shell is interac‐
>           tive.
> ```

So for example

```
 % read name\?"what's your name? "
what's your name?
```

(the `?` needs to be escaped here to prevent the shell treating it as a globbing character) or

```
 % read "name?what's your name? " 
what's your name?
```

See also:

- [read command in zsh throws error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198372/read-command-in-zsh-throws-error)
- [ZSH: Read command fails within bash function “read:1: -p: no coprocess”](https://superuser.com/questions/555874/zsh-read-command-fails-within-bash-function-read1-p-no-coprocess)